# Celebrity claims of veganism are everywhere--omission?

Tags: grammar

> Interest in vegan food has been booming across the rich world. Celebrity **claims** of veganism are everywhere: Bill Clinton and Al Gore, Serena and Venus Williams, Lewis Hamilton, Mike Tyson, Beyoncé, take your pick. [(source)](https://www.economist.com/briefing/2018/10/13/why-people-in-rich-countries-are-eating-more-vegan-food)

According to grammar rules, is this sentence right (marked with a word in bold)?

To me, it's more like to be "Celebrity **who** claims of veganism are everywhere".

Is this an omission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The word **claims** is a plural noun there, not a verb.  The word **celebrity** is a noun used as an adjectival modifier. The phrase **celebrity claims** means "claims by celebrities".